# Sencha Dataview xtype doesnt disply - But can see it in DEV TOOLS

Tags: extjs, touch, dataview

[image]I am working on a sample Sencha Poject and came across dataview and wanted to implement it.

After breaking my head for a long time - I saw that the dataview's do exist - But doesnt display.

here is teh the screen shot

```
Ext.define('VideoLibrary.view.VideoView', {
extend:'Ext.Conta![enter image description here][2]iner',
xtype:'videoView',

requires: [
    'VideoLibrary.model.Video'
],


config:{
    layout: 'fit',

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'dataview',
            scrollable: true,
            inline: true,
            itemCls:'dataViewElm',
            itemTpl: '<div>{video_name}</div>',
            store: 'Videos'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Comment: remove the layout : 'fit' and add height : '100%' within dataview

Comment: Doesnt Work :( - Thanks though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. In the parent Container - I did not set the layout. Once I set the layout in the parent Container - It worked perfectly

```
        layout:'card',
```